# Music file extension retrieval in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to retrieve the extension of music file in Windows Phone 8.0 using C# code? By extension I mean MP3, MP4, OGG etc.

Below is my code to get the songs from the music library:

```
MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();
SongCollection col = lib.Songs;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. SongCollection is basically an IEnumerable of Song and the Song class only contains Name, Artist and Album according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.aspx).